# How to describe TS interface for history.goBack in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Could help me please to type history.goBack in React? At the moment I use type any but I think its a wrong way.

Main.tsx

```
...
<Route path={PAGE_404} component={Page404} />
```

Page404.tsx

```
const Page404: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <section className={styles.section}>
      <GoBackLink text={'Назад'} onGoBackClick={() => history.goBack()} />
          ...
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Page404;
```

GoBackLink.tsx with interface and type any for onGoBackClick key

```
interface IGoBackLinkProps {
  text: string;
  onGoBackClick: any;
}

const GoBackLink: React.FC<IGoBackLinkProps> = ({ text, onGoBackClick }) => {
  return (
    <Link className={styles.link} to='/' onClick={onGoBackClick}>
      {text}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default GoBackLink;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onGoBackClick: () => void` or `onGoBackClick: Function`

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one question...is this best practice for such cases?

Comment: use `Function` with you don't pass parameters into it. `() => void` if you want pass

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IGoBackLinkProps {
  text: string;
  onGoBackClick(): void;
}
```

...if you don't need any parameters and don't care about return value in this callback function.